# Plot multiple random graph in one plot python

Tags: python

I want to plot multiple plot in one graph, each plot is a random plot of stoichatic python code here;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=20
x=[10]
b=0.02
d=0.03

for i in range(0,1000):
    if x[i]<N:
        birth_prob=b*x[i]
    else:
        birth_prob=0
    death_prob=d*x[i]
    random=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if random<birth_prob:
        xi=x[i]+1
    elif random<birth_prob+death_prob:
        xi=x[i]-1
    else:
        xi=x[i]
    x.append(xi)

plt.plot(x)
```

How can I put at least 10 different plots in one figure?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

you should always use matplotlib plots as an object, such as:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

This makes it a lot clearer what you're doing and allows you to plot several lines/scatter/etc on the same axes. Note: This was a bit confusing to me first, but matplotlib calls a 'plot' an axes. So it doesn't have anything to do with the X, Y axis on the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rows = 5
cols = 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(7,14))

for row in range(0,rows):
    for col in range(0,cols):
        N=20
        x=[10]
        b=0.02
        d=0.03

        for i in range(0,1000):
            if x[i]<N:
                birth_prob=b*x[i]
            else:
                birth_prob=0
            death_prob=d*x[i]
            random=np.random.uniform(0,1)
            if random<birth_prob:
                xi=x[i]+1
            elif random<birth_prob+death_prob:
                xi=x[i]-1
            else:
                xi=x[i]
            x.append(xi)

        ax[row][col].plot(x)
```

Comment: I try my updated code and yours but plot show 10 same objects and its scale move from 1000 to 10000 cause it duplicate object not random it.

It results like this;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EX2DxlWwgseo5xMP6eOhht3UyYUw3nP/view
But I want like this but have 10 objects
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ofw4D4OF4-u2iCoq3FkH3zRW__9Yf8c3/view

Comment: Okay, got you. Edited my code snippet. This should work as you expect it.